# Console app won't exit when given ctrl + c in debug mode

Tags: c#

When I run the below in Release, pressing `CTRL + C` successfully terminates the application.

When running in Debug, pressing `CTRL + C` hangs in the `while` loop below.

Why? Is there a way around this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Press CTRL + C...
        // When running in Release, the app closes down
        // When running in Debug, it hangs in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to achieve this is to use [`Console.CancelKeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Occurs when the Control modifier key `(Ctrl)` and either the
>   `ConsoleKey.C` console key (C) or the Break key are pressed
>   simultaneously `(Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break)`.
>
> When the user presses either `Ctrl+C` or `Ctrl+Break`, the `CancelKeyPress`
>   event is fired and the application's `ConsoleCancelEventHandler` event
>   handler is executed. The event handler is passed a
>   `ConsoleCancelEventArgs` object

---

**Example**

```
private static bool keepRunning = true;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) {
         e.Cancel = true;
         keepRunning = false;
      };

   while (keepRunning) 
   {
      // Do stuff
   }
   Console.WriteLine("exited gracefully");
}
```